# Why i cant call time that less then 6:00

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I cant call the time that i want im using the sytext

```
$sql="select kedatangan.id,pelajar.nama,kedatangan.masa 
    from pelajar 
    join kedatangan on pelajar.barcode= kedatangan.barcode 
    where 'masa' <= "8:00" order by id;";
```

But it doesn't work as i want..but when i change this `<` to this `>` it can call but it call all the data without following this statment

Comment: You need to change the quotes around `masa` to backticks.

Comment: I already change masa using backtick but it still give negative respond

Comment: Can you show some sample table contents? What is the datatype of the `masa` column?

Comment: You have another quoting problem. The double quotes around `8:00` will end the PHP string. You should be getting a PHP parse error from this.

Comment: Either put single quotes around the whole string, or single quotes around `8:00`.

Comment: thanks @barmar i already solve this problem